# Hide Menu depending on Role using laravel-permission in Nuxtjs Doesnt Work

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm building web App using `nuxtjs and Vuetify` for frontend and laravel for Backend. I want to hide menu depending on Role when user authenticated. I use `laravel spatie` and `laravel-permission` package for set permission also.

I want to bind `v-role="role"` value but it doesn't work.

Here my code in Vuetify:

```
<v-list dense rounded>
    <div v-for="(item, i) in menus" :key="i" router exact>
        <v-list-item v-if="!item.children" :key="i" :to="item.to">
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>
                    <v-icon left>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                    {{ item.name }}
                </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-list-group :v-role="role" v-else :key="i.name" :value="false">
            <template v-slot:activator>
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                        <v-icon left>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                        {{ item.name }}
                    </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </template>
            <v-list-item
                v-for="(subMenu, i) in item.children"
                :to="subMenu.to"
                :key="i"
                exact
                class="subMenu"
                v-role="'administrator'"
            >
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                        <v-icon left>{{ subMenu.icon }}</v-icon>
                        {{ subMenu.name }}
                    </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
    </div>
</v-list>
```

And Here my script code:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                toggle: true,
                menus: [
                    {
                        name: "Dashboard",
                        icon: "mdi-view-dashboard",
                        to: "/",
                        role: "administrator",
                    },
                ]
          }
       }
</script>
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: permission is a board topic....But in your scenario maybe it's worth to check this plugin https://github.com/williamcruzme/laravel-permissions

Comment: @ChrisChen bro, i used this package also

Comment: So what is the main issue? Is it not working for you?

Comment: @ChrisChen i  want to hide my sidebar menu on different Role, but i dont know how to implement it.

Comment: You can use `can`, `hasRole`,`hasPermissionTo` functions determine if a user can access a section or has a role.

Comment: @Jainil bro i updated my question , pls take a look

Comment: @z3r0 are you talking about your subMenu? Have you try to add `v-role="'user'"` to your v-list-item?

Comment: @ChrisChen its work if i do like that, but to `bind` value. 
Ex. `:v-role="role"` like this